# How to populate an HTMLTableCell with only dates selected in dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm creating a POS system that has a sales report page, in the sales report page I need to be able to select dates for the results to be inbetween but everything I have tried won't work with an HTML table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<Receipt> saleReport = Receipt.GetReceipts();
        List<Product> products = Product.GetProducts();
        List<OrderLine> orderLines = OrderLine.GetOrderLines();
        List<Inventory> inventories = Inventory.GetInventorys();
        List<ServiceOrder> serviceOrders = ServiceOrder.GetServiceOrders();
        List<Service> services = Service.GetServices();

        foreach (Receipt saleRep in saleReport)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

            //OrdNum Data
            HtmlTableCell cellOrder = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellOrder.InnerText = saleRep.ordNumber.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cellOrder);

            //Cust Data
            HtmlTableCell cellCustomer = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellCustomer.InnerText = saleRep.custID.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cellCustomer);

            //emp Data
            HtmlTableCell cellEmp = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellEmp.InnerText = saleRep.empID.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cellEmp);

            //Date Data
            HtmlTableCell cellDate = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellDate.InnerText = saleRep.ordDate.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cellDate);

            //Product Data
            HtmlTableCell cellProduct = new HtmlTableCell();
            foreach (OrderLine order in orderLines)
            {
                if (order.receiptID == saleRep.ID)
                {
                    foreach (Inventory inventory in inventories)
                    {
                        if (inventory.ID == order.inventoryID)
                        {
                            foreach (Product product in products)
                            {
                                if (product.ID == inventory.productID)
                                {
                                    cellProduct.InnerText = product.prodName;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            row.Cells.Add(cellProduct);

            //Service Data
            HtmlTableCell cellService = new HtmlTableCell();
            foreach (ServiceOrder serviceOrder in serviceOrders)
            {
                if (serviceOrder.receiptID == saleRep.ID)
                {
                    foreach (Service service in services)
                    {
                        if (service.ID == serviceOrder.serviceID)
                        {
                            cellService.InnerText = service.serName;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            row.Cells.Add(cellService);

            //Warranty Data
            HtmlTableCell cellWarranty = new HtmlTableCell();
            foreach (ServiceOrder serviceOrder in serviceOrders)
            {
                if (serviceOrder.receiptID == saleRep.ID)
                {
                    cellWarranty.InnerText = serviceOrder.serOrdWarranty.ToString();
                }
            }
            row.Cells.Add(cellWarranty);

            //Payment Data
            HtmlTableCell cellPayment = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellPayment.InnerText = Payment.GetPayments().Where(x => x.ID == saleRep.paymentID).FirstOrDefault().payType.ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cellPayment);

            //ProductCost Data
            HtmlTableCell cellProductCost = new HtmlTableCell();
            foreach (OrderLine order in orderLines)
            {
                if (order.receiptID == saleRep.ID)
                {
                    cellProductCost.InnerText = order.ordLinePrice.ToString();
                }

            }
            row.Cells.Add(cellProductCost);

            //ServiceCost Data
            HtmlTableCell cellServiceCost = new HtmlTableCell();
            foreach (ServiceOrder serviceOrder in serviceOrders)
            {
                if (serviceOrder.receiptID == saleRep.ID)
                {
                    foreach (Service service in services)
                    {
                        if (service.ID == serviceOrder.serviceID)
                        {
                            cellServiceCost.InnerText = service.serPrice.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            row.Cells.Add(cellServiceCost);





            tblSaleRep.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row" runat="server" id="ddlDate" visible="false">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Date</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="date-from">From:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-from">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="date-to">To:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-to">
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="tblSaleRep" runat="server" visible="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SO#</th>
            <th>Customer#</th>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Warrenty</th>
            <th>Paytype</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
            <th>Service Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbbSales"></tbody>
</table>
```